# Buffer always flushed after calling writev

Tags: c, file, file-io, buffer

I'm opening and using a file as follows:

```
stream = fopen(fd, "a");
setvbuf(stream, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ);
...
do {
    l = writev(fileno(f), iov, n);
    //The last iovec is the LF character
} while (l < 0 && errno == EINTR);
```

The error checking code is ommitted for clarity.

Why the output buffer is flushed after each call to `writev`? Executing `ls` in the directory where the file is located shows me a bigger size after each call to `writev`. Doing a `cat` on the file after each call to `writev` shows me the new record. I precise the last `iovec` is the `LF` character (however, the stream is not line buffered).

I checked that:

- The file is not closed after calling `writev`.
- The stream is fully buffered (the call to `setvbuf` succeeds, a call to `__flbf` returns 0).
- There is no call to `fflush` after `writev`.

Thanks, Mickael

Comment: The `writev` function is lower level than the C I/O streams, and writes directly to the file descriptor. It know nothing of the higher-level buffers. In fact, the C I/O stream function *uses* the lower level `write` function when it writes the buffer. You shouldn't really mix C I/O stream functions with the lower-level functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So, using the low level functions should give bad performance since there is no buffering? I have a VoIP application that writes a lot of records continuously and I discovered that the writes took too much time to execute, so I thought about using buffering so that records are flushed when N records are present. Is there an high level function that allows buffering and that works with the same model as writev?

Comment: It *might* give worse performance. It might also give better performance. It all depends on your use-cases. And no, there's no C standard function that works similar to `writev`. Worst case, you have to implement your own buffering on top of `writev`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg In my case, my application is writing CSV records continuously. Each record is represented by an array of iovec, that contains both values and delimiters between values. The values are generally small buffers (a few bytes). I'm thinking if it's not better to create a contiguous buffer for the records and then to use the regular write function.

Comment: That sounds like a better solution. But do remember to measure that solution, and compare with your current solution, to see which might be better.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, any success with improving this?